# Click() function on link text not working

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I am trying to open a site through TestNG, a security page is coming and for that I have click a link text "Continue to this website(not recommended)." that i have done through TestNG coding but it is giving *java.lang.NullPointerException* error.

and this is the code which i am trying......

```
 public class Registration {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebElement element;
    WebElement element2;
    WebDriverWait waiter;
     @Test(priority = 1)
    public void register_With_Cash() throws RowsExceededException, BiffException, WriteException, IOException 
      {
        File file = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

        driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("https://172.25.155.250/loginpage.aspx");        
        sleep(10000);

        waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Continue to this website (not recommended).")));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue to this website (not recommended).")).click();
        sleep(50000);
```

Thanx in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Which line is giving you the exception?

Comment: this one..............waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Continue to this website (not recommended).")));

Comment: please paste your exception and the exact line at your source code where it happens

Comment: So, where did you set `waiter` to something?  You DID set it to something, right?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.tcs.medmantra.Registration.register_With_Cash(Registration.java:54)......that means in  waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Continue to this website (not recommended).")));

Comment: waiter null maybe? did you put a breakpoint there to debug it?

Comment: now check it ....i hv reposted my code..

Comment: i dont see anywhere waiter to be initialized

Comment: @Apostolos.....i dont think waiter need to be initialized....its working fine with othere link text in another code

Comment: and if i m removing that waiter from the code....its showing  "Unable to find element with link text == Continue to this website (not recommended)." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below javascript to click the `Continue to the Website(not recommended)` link.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

Comment: but it is giving warning "the method GoToUrl(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver.Navigation"

Comment: i have modified to "driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");" .....now it is working....thanx a lot